# Cannot use prewritten comments

Tags: bug

I installed the script extension in Chrome 16.0.912.63 on Windows 7, but I can't insert prewritten comments. I click on Auto and it shows me the default comments, but when I select one of them, the Insert button is blocked and I can't insert the comment, but I can just cancel and press the other functions.
Am I doing something wrong or is there a problem with the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's a problem with the script, see the comments to the first answer here:

- https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se

Hopefully it will be fixed soon!